# trying to get json field value with 3rd foreach inside foreach

Tags: php

I am trying to get value of subscriber id but i am getting php error on 3rd foreach.

```
$content = '{"12345":{"id":"123","data":{"sort":"desc","subcriber":{"id":321"}}}';
$json = json_decode($content, true);

foreach($json as $row => $val) {
    echo $val['id'];
    $jdata = $val['data'];

    foreach($jdata as $data => $val2) {
        echo $val2['sort'];
        $jsubcriber = $val2['subcriber'];

        foreach($jsubcriber as $subcriber => $val3) {
            echo $val3['id'];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you iterate over this data set anyhow? Apart from the first level, the contained fields don't appear to be lists.

Comment: i am actually getting these field through a url.

`$url = 'http://example.com/fieldlisting.php';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);`

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
echo $jsubscriber['id'];
```

`$jsubscriber` is an associative array, not an array of associative arrays.